# I git pull on digitalocean but when I run npm install comes an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, digital-ocean, package.json

```
npm ERR! Merge conflict detected in your package.json.
npm ERR! Please resolve the package.json conflict to retry the command:
```

I have tried the `npm-merge-driver` but still coming the same error.

Comment: You either got a merge conflict after the pull and you need to resolve it, or somebody committed a package.json file *with* the merge conflict into it. In either case, it's likely not solvable by any packages but the file needs to be repaired manually. If it's a merge conflict after pull, then resolving that should be easy.

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ. Could you tell me how can I spot the error to repair on package.json?

Comment: You can manually look at `package.json` file, the conflicted blocks will be having markers like `<<<<<<`, `=======`, `>>>>>>>`, and fix it. It may be easy to fix it with some editors too like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) if you are using. Or you can use some merge tools. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/2873538).

Comment: Great, mate! Thanks, @AjeetShah!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you might have duplicate keys in your package.json file.
To fix it:

**1. Open your package.json trace it for duplicate keys. To give you some ease start with the dependencies and devDependencies key.**

**2. If you find duplicate keys compare and copy and paste the dependencies that are not duplicated into one key and delete the rest.**

**3. Run npm install**

Example:
At the start, I had this.

```js
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "twrnc": "^3.0.2"
  },
```

after I compared and remove duplicate dependencies and one of the keys. I got this:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "twrnc": "^3.0.2"
  },
```

*You can also check your dev dependencies as well.
To avoid this problem in the future do not open your package.json file while installing packages.*